# Execute a file (installer) in Python and immediately exit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing an installer of sorts.  When a user runs my python file (compiled to executable), it downloads the actual installer then needs to run the installer and immediately exit (i.e. the real installer keeps running).  My question is how do I do this bit?  How do I execute the installer from the python script and exit immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [`os.exec*` functions](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execl):

> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded into the current process, and will have the same process id as the caller.

If you **must** exit the python script, may be you could use `subprocess.Popen` and then exit, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Thank you.  You get the accepted as you answered first.  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

you probably want something in the `os.exec*` family.  [Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management).  You don't have to exit: these functions will *replace* the current program with whatever you execute, which will take over the process.

Comment: +1 as I know what it feels like for somebody else to slip the same correct answer in just before me.  Thank you.